# Docker container sometimes hangs and cannot be stopped

Tags: linux, docker

Most of the time it just works, but sometime it will hang, and it cannot be stopped.

To be more specific, I run an image based on the official `httpd` image, sometime the webserver will return a timeout error. When I `exec -it my-httpd-container bash`, I can login into the container, but I cannot `ls` nor `ps` or other commands, and `docker stop my-httpd-container` will just hang there. I have to kill docker it self and start docker again.

I'm new to docker, and just learned some basics, How can I investigate it?

Comment: Check free memory, disk space, try to configure syslog within container

Comment: check what `docker logs your container` shows